# Display cancel button when the VC is presented, don't display cancel button when the same VC is pushed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbaritems

I have a ViewController that need to display in two places.

In first place, the VC need to present and dismiss using a cancel button in its navigation bar.

In second place, the VC need to push to a navigation stack(its presented modally too) and cannot close (user have to use the back button in navigation stack).

I can display the VC in both places correctly but cannot use the close button properly. When I add the cancel bar button item to the VC, it appears in both scenarios.
How can I show the cancel button when the VC is presented and hide it when the VC is pushed?

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` check if `self.presentingViewController` is nil or not, if its non nil than show cancel button else dont add any button to navigation bar

Comment: @SandeepBhandari This added the cancel button to both. Maybe because of the VC is pushed to a navigation stack which is already presenting as modal.

Comment: Than why cant you use `self.navigationController?.presentingViewController != nil` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using isBeingPresented you can manage your cancel button,

```
        if self.isBeingPresented {
           debugPrint("Controller is Presented")
        } else {
            debugPrint("Controller is Pushed")
         }
```

Comment: This doesn't add cancel button to the presented VC. Is it because VC is presented with a navigation controller?

Comment: Try below,
If you have btn outlet

btnCancel.isHidden = !self.isBeingPresented


If it is nav bar btn try below


self.navigationController.letBarButtonItem =  self.isBeingPresented ? btnCancel : nil

Comment: is it **absolutely** required for you to use the name 'Back' and 'Cancel' in two cases? Or what matters to you is just the **correct** functionality of dismissing VC in two different ways?
If it is the last one, I can help you